# How can I completely remove Dropbox from my Mac?

Tags: macbook, dropbox

I have only used Dropbox once but 4 years ago, and then deleted app, however recently I been looking inside my MacBook Air macOS (version 10.8.5) and found it there inside `Library/` and `Public/` folder: I have removed it from there but every single day I log into computer it shows up again and again at the same place :(

Can someone please give me step by step instructions how to get rid of it for good?

Here is what system log revealed about it. There is more but I think this kind of shows how is being implemented inside of my computer every day. I just need someone to tell me how to prevent this process from starting.

```
SYSTEM LOG QUERIES 

Diagnostic and usage information 

Dropbox_2018-06-10-18-412

Process:         Dropbox [1112]
Path:            /Volumes/VOLUME/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox
Identifier:      Dropbox
Version:         51.4.66 (51.4.66)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [1108]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2018-06-10 18:04:10.973 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000106e08212 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000106c9ab24 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000106cdef61 abort + 143
3   com.getdropbox.dropbox          0x0000000102ba2246 0x102ba1000 + 4678
4   com.getdropbox.dropbox          0x0000000102ba2835 0x102ba1000 + 6197
5   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000106c377e1 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000106e086d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000106c9bf1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000106c9bce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000106c86191 start_wqthread + 13
```

Comment: yes I am absolutely sure, there is No Dropbox app  visible on computer , I searched everywhere , i have removed some folders from library as well but I am afraid to remove move folders from library as I may mess up system since I am not expert

Comment: I have just found inside Library and inside Preferences folder following:  com.getdropbox.dropbox.plist   and also com.dropbox.DropboxMacUpdate.plist    Which I both removed, I will post update if this has solved my problem

Comment: Thank you, I have trashed 1 item that was there. Here is what I like to report: Dropbox blue folder shows up still inside Library still after every new log in :( Apple is just horrible/ invasive system to use. I have also found inside Library folder Ubiquity ( aka iCloud) I never ever used iCloud on Mac but this folder is there,,and same thing it keeps comming back after I trash it . I found bigger Ubiquity folder inside other Library on same Mac and trashed it, but then could't start up my system and had to restore comp :(